# In sqlite3, Can we convert a sql execute(.....callback function....) to a sqlite_prepare , step, finalize

Tags: c, database, sqlite

And in the step function, call the callback function(as its too big to replicate)
for eg:

---

```
sqlite3_exec(db,command,callback,0,error);
>>>>>>>>>>
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,command,-1,&stmt,NULL); 
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt); 
if(rc == SQLITE_ROW) 
    { INSERT CALLBACK FUNCTION HERE } 
else 
    do error checking or sqlite3 done etc 
sqlite3_finalize(stmt); 
...
//there is somewhere an 
//**static int callback (void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)**
```

---

And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
It's exactly what the [original implementation of `sqlite3_exec()`](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/ba1863ea58c4c840) does.

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot :)